# App installing on Cellphone but not showing on screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I am developing an android application using android studio, which has 2 activity so far, LoginActivity and the MainActivity, But when I run the application it installs in my cellphone or virtual machine, but does not appear anywhere. I looked into the installed application and the application is installed. I believe my problem is on the Manifest, but I do not know how to solve it.

The complete code is here on GitHub: https://github.com/SoftwareEngineeringClass/MobileApplication/tree/master/Minerva

and here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Minerva"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <itent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </itent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
</application>
```

Comment: You have 3 activities in your manifest, not 2. And I really don't think you should have a Facebook activity

Answer (score 0):

I believe the first thing I'd do is set a breakpoint at the beginning of the launcher Activity and see if execution gets there or not. No matter what Logcat will tell you something is wrong. You have to run it in debug mode of course. Attach the debugger. If you give me all your code I'd be more than happy to take a look and give you a definitive answer quickly.

Comment: Yeah sure! All the code is in the GitHub, right here: https://github.com/SoftwareEngineeringClass/MobileApplication/tree/master/Minerva

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if you require permissions? , maybe it is the problem that not allow you to run. Also if you can share your activity I can help you.

Comment: I think is a problem with butter knife  when you inject the view